# How does Holoviews know which colours to assign to each scatterplot in an overlay?

Tags: overlay, bokeh, holoviews

In the bokeh Holoviews gallery, there is an example called 'Scatter economic'.

http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/scatter_economic.html#bokeh-gallery-scatter-economic

In this plot, notice how one of the options for `Scatter` is (`color=Cycle('Category20')`). The last line of the plot is `gdp_unem_scatter.overlay('Country')`.

- My question is: How does Holoviews know to connect each `Scatter` to a particular color in `Cycle('Category20')`? Is this just a property of `Cycle()`? Is there some way that the `Overlay` interacts with the Scatter and with the Cycle automatically?
- A slightly related confusion is that if I use the .opts method instead of the cell magic as in the example, it still works. For example, if I use the `.opts` method with this cycle color on the `Scatter` (i.e., second to the last line in the above example), and *then* do an `.overlay('Country')`, somehow Holoviews knows to assign each Scatter to a particular color based on the Country.

I want to make sure that I am properly plotting what I intend to.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now possible to map categories in an NdOverlay (as is used in the example above) by using a so called dim expression and then define an expression to do the mapping:

```
dim_expr = hv.dim('category').categorize({'A': 'red', 'B': 'green', 'C': 'blue'})
overlay = hv.NdOverlay({chr(65+i): hv.Scatter(np.random.rand(10, 2)) for i in range(3)}, 'category')
overlay.opts(hv.opts.Scatter(color=dim_expr))
```

[image]

In this example we created a `dim` expression which points to the 'category' dimension and then maps each category ('A', 'B' and 'C') to a color ('red', 'green', 'blue'). We then just assign that to the color option.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Holoviews know to connect each Scatter to a particular color in Cycle('Category20')? Is this just a property of Cycle()? Is there some way that the Overlay interacts with the Scatter and with the Cycle automatically?

You are correct that `Cycle` and `Overlay` are designed to interact in this way automatically. More explicitly, each color in the `Cycle` gets assigned to a 'layer' of the overlay until the cycle runs out of colors and it loops.

> For example, if I use the .opts method with this cycle color on the Scatter (i.e., second to the last line in the above example), and then do an .overlay('Country'), somehow Holoviews knows to assign each Scatter to a particular color based on the Country.

This is because your call to `opts` customizes the options on the elements of the data structure before you call the `overlay` method on (this data structure is a `HoloMap`). The options set there are propagated to the `Scatter` elements in the `HoloMap` which will now have the chosen `Cycle` specified. This means that when these elements get put into an overlay, HoloViews can look up the `Cycle` appropriately and apply it correctly to the overlay.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you @jlstevens! That does make sense. I've noticed that one alternative to doing the overlay is to specify the coloured categories as a vdim and put color_index as an option in Scatter. However, this does not allow for the clickable legend.

Comment: is there a way to specify which colours map to which categories? So for example if I wanted Austria to be red, Belgium to be blue, etc; does Holoviews have this functionality?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to do such an explicit mapping currently, but I do think it is an excellent suggestion for a feature request. Would you mind filing an issue about this on the HoloViews Github repo?